# How to copy Tuples to clipboard

Tags: c#, wpf, tuples, clipboard

I have to copy three different data to the clipboard.
So I create a Tuple and copy it to the clipboard and then I copy it to clipboard

```
var newTuple = new Tuple<Component, Color?, bool?>(CopyComponent, headerColour_Copied, IsHeaderForegroundDark_Copied);
Clipboard.SetDataObject(newTuple);
```

when copying I get an exception which translated may sound like "Other data are available".
I also tried to purge the clipboard but that was of no help.

```
Clipboard.SetDataObject(CopyComponent);
Clipboard.SetDataObject(headerColour_Copied);
Clipboard.SetDataObject(IsHeaderForegroundDark_Copied);
```

Please notice that if I don't make a Tuple but set each datum separately everything is fine.

So can't tuples be copied to clipboard??

I also tried to box each of the three datum into an object without but still fails

Thanks for helping

Patrick

Comment: Side note (won't fix the problem), tuples have a static `Create` factory method that spares you the need to specify the generic types involved (compiler infers them from the passed arguments)

Comment: Hm, I wonder if it wouldn't be the generic type that's causing issues. Does it work with a `List<int>`?

Comment: Basically the clipboard involves unmanaged code, so I'm not trusting it can deal with .net generic types. Try sending a plain array of values instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generic types typically don't play very well outside the realm of . net; try sending a plain array of values instead:

```
Clipboard.SetDataObject(new object[] { CopyComponent, headerColour_Copied, IsHeaderForegroundDark_Copied });
```

Clipboard content can be consumed by any application; basic intrinsic types are a safer bet here.

Answer (score 2):

Fortunately, we can store `ValueTuple` or `Tuple` on the Clipboard and retrieve it as a serializable data object.

```cs
// using System.Windows;
public void TupleClipboardTest1()
{
    (int, string) original = (11, "Eleven");

    Clipboard.SetData(DataFormats.Serializable, original);

    object retrieved = Clipboard.GetData(DataFormats.Serializable);

    Debug.WriteLine(retrieved.GetType()); // System.ValueTuple`2[System.Int32,System.String]

    (int, string) restored = (ValueTuple<int, string>)retrieved;

    Debug.WriteLine(restored.Item1); // 11
    Debug.WriteLine(restored.Item2); // Eleven
}
```

```cs
// using System.Windows;
public void TupleClipboardTest2()
{
    Tuple<int, string> original = (11, "Eleven").ToTuple();

    Clipboard.SetData(DataFormats.Serializable, original);

    object retrieved = Clipboard.GetData(DataFormats.Serializable);

    Debug.WriteLine(retrieved.GetType()); // System.Tuple`2[System.Int32, System.String]

    Tuple<int, string> restored = (Tuple<int, string>)retrieved;

    Debug.WriteLine(restored.Item1); // 11
    Debug.WriteLine(restored.Item2); // Eleven
}
```

Of cource, its items must be serializable as well. Otherwise it causes a COMException.

```cs
// using System.Windows;
public void TupleClipboardTest3()
{
    (int, System.Windows.Media.Color) original = (11, System.Windows.Media.Colors.Gray);

    Clipboard.SetData(DataFormats.Serializable, original);

    object retrieved = Clipboard.GetData(DataFormats.Serializable); // System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Data on clipboard is invalid (0x800401D3 (CLIPBRD_E_BAD_DATA))'
}
```

Therefore, we need to convert an non-serializable item to a serializable object beforehand.

Comment: Thanks for your help but how can I make a not serilizable item to serializable? I don't understand your example. With color it is simple

Comment: Serialization itself is quite big topic to deal with. In general, if a data class has only members of primitive types, adding [SerializableAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.serializableattribute) could make it serializable. Anyway, it depends on each class.